# JPA entity compatibility for both SQL Server and Oracle (auto-increment column issues)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm developing a Java EE JBoss service which will be deployed in two different environments: one using SQL Server as the database, and a different one which uses Oracle 10g.

My database schemas are very similar, except that the primary key columns are identity-auto-increment in SQL Server and generated using sequences in Oracle.

With JPA, is it possible to use a single set of entities with both DB's?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can, but just specify the generated-value definition for the PK field in XML metadata rather than annotations. Use 2 different "orm.xml" files, so, for example, use "persistenceUnitOracle" for Oracle that references orm-oracle.xml, and "persistenceUnitSqlServer" for SQLServer that references orm-sqlserver.xml

Comment: Interesting concept, thanks.  Put the generated-value definition in XML and keep the rest of the metadata as annotations?

Comment: Yes. keep deployment-specific information in XML, whether it is value-generation, or column/table names or whatever, to avoid having to recompile to deploy in a different environment